# Error: Could not resolve 'login' from state 'app.home'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, routes

I am trying to convert a website to a mobile app and I encountered a problem. I am using `authO` for 3rd party authentication and when I am trying to log in to the app I got

> Error: Could not resolve 'login' from state 'app.home'

app.js:

```
 //Ionic Starter App

(function () {


  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', ['ionic', 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt'])
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'lockProvider', 'jwtOptionsProvider'];

  function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, lockProvider, jwtOptionsProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/menu/menu.html'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
              'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html'
              }
            }
          })
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
              'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'components/template/template.html'
              }
            }
          })
          .state('app.signin', {
              url: '/login',
              views: {
                'menuContent': {
                  templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html'
                }
              }
            });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');

    lockProvider.init({
      clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      options: {
        auth: {
          redirect: true,
          params: {
            scope: 'openid',
            device: 'Mobile device'
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // Configuration for angular-jwt
    jwtOptionsProvider.config({
      tokenGetter: function() {
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      },
      whiteListedDomains: ['localhost'],
      unauthenticatedRedirectPath: '/login'
    });
  }
})();
```

If I have the following routing it works:

```
.state('app', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'components/menu/menu.html'
 })
.state('app.home', {
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : 'components/home/home.html'
});


 >menu.html:
```

```html
<ion-side-menus  enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal" align-title="Center">
      <ion-nav-title>
          <img alt="Company Logo" height="45" src="img/Switch-Logo-top.jpg">
      </ion-nav-title>
      <!-- Left burger menu button -->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <!-- Right Log out button -->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
          <ion-buttons>
              <a href="#/app/login" class="button button-outline">
                  <button class="button" >Log In</button>
              </a>
          </ion-buttons>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!--  Left burger menu -->
  <ion-side-menu class="menu" side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
      <h1 class="title">Make Your Switch</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content ng-controller="menuController">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="todo in todos" menu-close href="#/app/dashboard">
          <div class="item-content" ng-click="clicked(todo.url)">
            {{todo.title}}
          </div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

but is not the routing that I need, I need to have the sliding menu on every page that I am, so the menu needs to abstract and be shown everywhere.
Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: What does your `menu.html` template look like?

Comment: I have added a code snippet

Comment: menu.html is using a controller that loads data form a json and renders the output and redirects each menu entry to a url specified inside the JSON. When using the authO, it cannot load the script form login.html because of that state provider form app.js. If I change the routing as I specified above it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was in the routing, inside the home.controller.js I had a state.go(login), but in app.js I did not had a match. Updated the state and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be that your menu.html is missing a `ui-view` directive.

Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view. [ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views ]

Therefore, your child view `app.home` will be expecting it's parent `app`'s template `menu.html` to have `<div ui-view></div>` at some point within it's HTML.

Comment: Are you sure? For example for login it loads without having to add a <div ui-view> in the menu.html and keeps the menu attached to the login.